add "use client" into index.ts that exports all of component stuffs
I am using nextjs 14 and I create all components in src/components directory and each component has index.ts file that will exports all of my components stuffs such as subcomponents, types, context and etc.
when I use it inside client component from index.ts it is work perfectly but the problem is when I use that components and subcomponents in a server component it goes to throw error that you can not use client stuffs in server component
I know the problem came from index.ts file because this file exports all of my components, subcomponents, util functions and etc. and when import one of my server component from index.ts inside another server components it will import client stuffs too. so by adding "use client" inside index.ts the problem will be fixed but I just want to know by adding "use client" in index.ts will be all component stuffs considered as client or not?

I'm not sure if I fully understood your question. If you are exporting both client and some server components from an index file and you add the "use client" directive at the top of that index file, it will mark the entire module as a client module. This means any module/component exported imported from the index file, including server components, will be sent to and run by the client. However, if you do not import a server component from the index file, and import it directly from its own file, which doesn't have a use client directive, it will be evaluated on the server.

Yes you are absolutely right and it is possible to import then from their own files but I wanted to know if there is a way to import all the files from one path for example instead of importing the components from their original path for example "/clientComponent" or "/serverComponent" import them from the "" path. The way that came to my mind was to create two files named index.server.ts and index.client.ts and export the server and client components in each separate file but when I want to import them I have to put "/index.{server or client}" in the path.
